# More effective way to filter data in R

Tags: r

Is there a neat way to select only certain rows from a list.
For example, let us say I have a list of villages and their populations.
village - population
Aa - 10
Bb - 55
Cc -33
Ca - 45
Ab -39

I am looking for a neat way to keep only those rows that in the village name there is no "a" (those would be Bb, Cc, and Ab).

```
d #file read in with read_delim
list <- d$village #this would return the list of villages
list_result <- list() 
counter <- 1
#create a new list containing only desired villages
for (village in list){
  if (!stri_detect_fixed(village, "a")){
     list_result[counter] = village
     counter = counter +1
  }
}

data_final <- d %>% 
  filter(village %in% list_result)
```

I have the feeling this is to much beginners code, so I want to improve it and make it more effective. Are there any ways to achieve the same only with less code?

Comment: Can you pleaes `dput` the example.  Do you have a `list` or data.frame

Comment: I am reading in a file with read_delim.. I guess its return type is list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing a `for` loop

```
d[grep('a', d$village, inverse = TRUE),]
```

---

Or with `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
d %>%
  filter(!str_detect(village, 'a'))
```